# Start SSIS Package from Script Task "InProcess"

Tags: c#, sql-server, ssis, ssis-2012

I want to start a child SSIS package from *Script Task* and do it in scope of main SSIS package execution. Like it is done by SSIS *Execute Package Task* when you set *ExecuteOutOfProcess* property equal to `false`.

However, tutorials I have found, starting from [Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/ssis-quickstart-run-dotnet?view=sql-server-2017) etc, are creating a new execution. This is equivalent to setting *ExecuteOutOfProcess* property equal to `true`.
In that case you do not inherit all project configurations, parameters from your current execution instance, and have to set it again. Execution in SSISDB log is independent and is not linked with master package. Moreover, caches are not reused among different DTSExec processes.

Any idea how to start child package from the same SSISDB Project at Script Task?

The idea behind is to create a *Script Task* which will start child packages in parallel, feeding in specific parameters. With *Script Task* I can achieve parallelism, and *InProcess* execution keeps small RAM footprint.

Comment: And you _don't_ want to use the existing Execute Package Task? You can parallelize workloads by having multiple EPT being fed from something like a [workpile pattern](http://www.andrewleesmith.co.uk/2016/09/23/the-work-pile-pattern/)

Comment: @billinkc, thanks for sharing, to think the problem from different angle. At first look it's another way around the existing design, where master package implicitly builds a processing queue and executes it.  
Problem with *Exec Package Task* is that parallelism degree is not flexible, it is fixed with number of EPT you put in package. As the working approach - put enough of ETP to utilize internal parallelism limits of SSIS executor.